# Why I get error this error (AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'?) on sqllite command?

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3
from tkinter.ttk import Combobox

root = Tk()
conn = sqlite3.connect('customer_1.db')
c  = conn.cursor()
data= c.execute("select name from sqlite_master where type = 'table';")
data = c.fetchall()
combo1 = Combobox(root, values=data).pack()
data2 =c.execute('select customer_name from {tb}'.format(tb=combo1.get()))
data2 = c.fetchall()
combo2 = Combobox(root, values=data2).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

the line `Combobox(root, values=data).pack()` returns None

you probably meant to do this instead:

```
combo1 = Combobox(root, values=data)
combo1.pack()
```